# Getting Singular Values of NumPy Data Columns in Order

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, svd

I would like to calculate the singular value decomposition of a matrix and the order of the singular values is important. By default, it seems `numpy.linalg.svd` (and `scipy.linalg.svd`) sort the singular values, which makes it impossible for me to tell which column corresponds to each singular value.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-74, 80, 18, -56, -112],
              [14, -69, 21, 52, 104],
              [66, -72, -5, 764, 1528],
              [-12, 66, -30, 4096, 8192],
              [3, 8, -7, -13276, -26552],
              [4, -12, 4, 8421, 16842]])

U, D, V = np.linalg.svd(X)
print(D)
```

Returns:

```
array([3.63684045e+04, 1.70701331e+02, 6.05331879e+01, 7.60190176e+00,
        1.17158094e-12])
```

When I need:

```
array([1.70701331e+02, 6.05331879e+01, 7.60190176e+00, 3.63684045e+04, 
        1.17158094e-12])
```

Is there a way to get the singular values (D) such that they are unsorted? The relation X = UDV^T must also be preserved.

**Edit:** Some context was needed here to elucidate my misunderstanding. I was trying to reproduce Section 2.3, Variance Decomposition Method in [this paper](http://sitesusa.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/242/2014/05/Liao_2012FCSM_VI-A.pdf).

Comment: User has also crossposted this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404288/getting-singular-values-of-numpy-data-columns-in-order

Comment: When you're saying "which makes it impossible for me to tell which column corresponds to each singular value"
what columns are you talking about ?  those of the unitary basis U and the conjugate transpose V ?

Comment: I have since removed the crossposting, and I appreciate your constructive questions and feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say:

> By default, it seems numpy.linalg.svd (and scipy.linalg.svd) sort the singular values, which makes it impossible for me to tell which column corresponds to each singular value.

I think you're making a mistake, there are no unique order in the singular values in the "Singular value decomposition", all that matters is that order of column vectors of U, D & V are such that:
`U * D * V == X`

That's why, by convention, they are put in descending order, but obviously the vertical vectors of the unitary basis U and the conjugate transpose V are also set in an order such that the formula above holds.

If you want a proof, to compute X back from U, D & V, you have to do:

```
from scipy import linalg

#decompose
U, D, V = np.linalg.svd(X)

# get dim of X
M,N = X.shape

# Construct sigma matrix in SVD (it simply adds null row vectors to match the dim of X 
Sig = linalg.diagsvd(D,M,N)

# Now you can get X back:
assert np.sum(np.dot(U, np.dot(Sig, V)) - X) < 0.00001
```

Comment: I see, so, if I wanted to calculate [variance-decomposition proportions](http://sitesusa.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/242/2014/05/Liao_2012FCSM_VI-A.pdf) for example, the singular values have no ordinal meaning when used to analyze the variance of the parameter estimates. It is the respective relation to the singular value that is important.

Comment: Absolutely - and it is well said.  It's like when you want to deform an object whether your first rotate or first scale it, it doesn't change the finale result.